# Syntax error with sql query

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have this block of code that executes within my function but it keeps saying there is a syntax error. Am I missing something? Because it seems fine to me

```
 string query3 = "INSERT INTO dbo.Liguanea_Progress VALUES('" + comboBox2.Text + "' '" + textBox5.Text + "' '" + textBox2.Text + "' '" + comboBox3.Text + "''" + textBox3.Text + "''" + comboBox1.Text + "');";
```

Comment: I don't see any commas between columns

Comment: @Lamak I approached this query like how I did it in SQL without the columns. Do I have to include the columns in my c# code?

Comment: what do you mean "how I did it in SQL without the columns"?. In SQL you should have `INSERT INTO Table VALUES('a','b','c')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string query3 = "INSERT INTO dbo.Liguanea_Progress(col1) VALUES('" + textBox.Text + "')";
```

Use this pattern for consequent columns involved and respective values. It is important to declare the columns involved when doing an insert query as well to avoid confusion.

Furthermore, I assume you're using ADO.net judging from this code snippet. You may want to parametize the query to prevent SQL injection like so:

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Col1", textBox.Text));
```

Which now makes your query like this:

```
string query3 = "INSERT INTO dbo.Liguanea_Progress(col1) VALUES(@Col1)";
```

This makes the sql code easier to edit.

Answer (score 3):

1. When using `insert`, always include the column names. So, your query should be `INSERT INTO dbo.Liguanea_Progress(col1, col2, . . .)`.
2. Never just stuff user input into a query string. Although one reason is that doing so makes the code susceptible to SQL injection, another important reason is that you might introduce syntax errors. Use parameterized queries.
3. The values in `VALUES()` should be separated by commas, not spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Your query syntax is invalid. You need to have commas after every paramter.

```
string query3 = "INSERT INTO dbo.Liguanea_Progress VALUES(@Param1, @Param2,@Param3, @Param4, @Param5, @Param6);
```

Also start using sql command parameters to protect you from sql injection. Also this gives you clear view on your query.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = query3;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param1", comboBox2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param2", textBox5.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param3", textBox2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param4", comboBox3.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param5", textBox3.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param6", comboBox1.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing commas and brackets between your values, try something like this

```
string query3 = "INSERT INTO dbo.Liguanea_Progress VALUES('" + comboBox2.Text + "'),('" + textBox5.Text + "'),('" + textBox2.Text + "'),('" + comboBox3.Text + "'),('" + textBox3.Text + "'),('" + comboBox1.Text + "');";
```

You'll need brackets around each value if you're inserting multiple values into the same column. If you're inserting this into one row then you're just missing the commas;

```
string query3 = "INSERT INTO dbo.Liguanea_Progress VALUES('" + comboBox2.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + comboBox3.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + comboBox1.Text + "');";
```